# Проверка подключения к интернету при старте приложения Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В общем есть приложение, имеет 3 активити:

1. Loading Page (splash screen);
2. WebView для конкретного сайта;
3. Активити с картинкой об отсутствии интернета.

Вопрос: как во время работы 1 активити проверить подключение к интернету и, в случае если его нет, кинуть на 3 активити, а если есть, то на 2?

Comment: Никак. Правильно - обрабатывать ошибки по факту. Подключение может исчезнуть и в тот короткий момент, что между проверкой и окончанием загрузки сайта. А еще отсутствие подключения далеко не единственная причина проблем с доступом. После того, как не удалось подгрузить сайт, уже можно попытаться установить причину и дать юзеру соотв. указания.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно советуют решения на базе `ConnectivityManager`, но оно показывает лишь **факт подключения к какой-либо сети**, что не говорит о том, что есть связь с интернетом. Если вы подключитесь к локальной сети по Wi-fi, то метод вернёт `true`, но доступа к интернету может и не быть, т.к. это локальная сеть.

Я бы рекомендовал пинговать адрес, чтоб наверняка сказать, есть ли инет:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
```

Можно прям из UI потока.

Или подключиться попробовать:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        int timeoutMs = 1500;
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

        sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
        sock.close();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) { return false; }
}
```

Нужен пермишен:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Но это не будет работать в UI потоке, нужно завернуть, к примеру, в `AsyncTask`:

```
class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

    private Consumer mConsumer;
    public  interface Consumer { void accept(Boolean internet); }

    public  InternetCheck(Consumer consumer) { mConsumer = consumer; execute(); }

    @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) { try {
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53), 1500);
        sock.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) { return false; } }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Boolean internet) { mConsumer.accept(internet); }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
new InternetCheck(internet -> { /* делаем здесь что-то после получения результата */ });
```

---

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Comment: Еще пока не проверял на реальном устройстве, но на эмуляторе всегда возвращается false

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isConnected()){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityThree.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public boolean isConnected() {
    boolean connected = false;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        connected = nInfo != null && nInfo.isAvailable() && nInfo.isConnected();
        return connected;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Connectivity Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return connected;
}
```